# HTML IE specific code

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Can I use specific html if the browser is IE? (Assuming FF is the default browser)
Foe example:

```
html line 1  

if IE 
html line 2  
else
html line 2  

html line 3    
html lin3 4
```

I am aware of using different CSS, but that won't work for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Browser Conditionals:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124/is-there-a-list-of-browser-conditionals-for-use-including-stylesheets

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure - [**conditional comments**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

IE understands "conditional comments," which you can use to selectively show markup even to specific versions.  Here's an introduction:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to offer a bit more explanation, since a solution to your question necessarily involves both "downlevel-revealed" and "downlevel-hidden" conditional comments. Both work very well in Internet Explorer, but it's in non-Microsoft browsers that the distinction becomes important:

Content inside "Downlevel-revealed" conditional comments will **always** display in non-Microsoft browsers (since they **do not** follow the standard `<!--  -->` syntax of HTML comments).

Content inside "Downlevel-hidden" conditional comments (which seem to be discussed more often) will **never** show up in other browsers (since they **do** follow the standard `<!--  -->` syntax of HTML comments).

So, marking up your example code:

```
html line 1

<!--[if IE]>
html line 2
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
html line 2  
<![endif]>

html line 3
html lin3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional comments for code only IE reads:

```
<!--[if IE]>
IE only code here.
<![endif]-->
```

Or PHP:

```
<?php
   function ae_detect_ie()
   {
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
     (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
        return true;
          else
         return false;
    }
  ?>

<?php  if (ae_detect_ie()) { code here } else { code here }  ?>
```

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is using Javascript to check which browser is being used. You could have default HTML in your file and then hava Javascript change it out, or add to it, if the user is using IE.