# Layout problems in IE7

Tags: layout, internet-explorer-7, rendering

Our website www.phototulip.com displays fine in Safari and Firefox but not in IE7.

The main content seems to display on the bottom right hand side and the nav bar shifts slightly to the left. I've tried to adjust sidebar and content widths but with no success.

I was wondering if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few places where your markup is invalid (one or more `<div>` tags aren't closed properly) that could, potentially affect the layout.  FireFox tends to be a bit more forgiving about that sort of thing than IE.

[image]

Other things to check are that your content area & sidebar have explicit widths set and that they aren't too wide for the container they're in.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. OK I seem to have sorted the layout. The main nav is still shifting left though. It just seems to render differently. I can only make it look OK in IE  if I adjust the margins - this obviously then changes it in Safari/Firefox!

Comment: There may be a better solution for your specific case but you could always use a Browser Conditional to just adjust the margins in IE:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124/is-there-a-list-of-browser-conditionals-for-use-including-stylesheets

Comment: I have it sorted finally! Thanks very much for you help Mark. Much appreciated.